# jQuery toggle DIV overlaps toggle link in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I am having a headache with IE7.

I have a `div` that gets toggled by an anchor (CSS `position: relative`) below it.

In all good browsers, the `div` toggles as expected and everything moves up and down to accommodate this.

In IE7, the `div` toggles as expected, but the anchor that is CSS `position: relative` seems to remain in its original location as though it was CSS `position: fixed`.

I took away the `position: relative` and the entire thing works as expected (similar to other browsers).

Am I missing something here? Does IE7 have an issue with relative items below a togged item?

Thanks for any help in advance...

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsfiddle and post it? That would be very helpful.

Comment: It is a very large amount of HTML, CSS and JS... still want it posting to jsfiddle?

Comment: If you want help debugging your code in IE, it helps to have the code.

Comment: can't seem to replicate it in jsfiddle either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `position: fixed;` instead... works well!

Answer (score 0):

It's always good if you can include either screenshots or, more preferably, a working example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). From what I understand though, an easily applied fix would be to just have an ie7 only css stylesheet that overrides the formatting that is messed up in ie7. Here is an example:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="someFileName.css">
<![endif]-->
```

I got that snippet from [this site](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/ie7-only-css-hacks/) which contains a couple of other ways of doing it if you don't find that one to your liking. Good luck!